# File versions using ?v=(file version)

Tags: javascript, css, version

I have seen some sites add a version parameter to their `.css` and `.js` files like `style.CSS?v=60` meaning the file is of version 60. The sites I have seen to do this cache their files long in the future.

Do I need to add any new code to my files or can I just update my code and then when a change is made change the version parameter `?v=`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to employ this technique, then the first step is to set your web-server to send far-future expires headers, for certain file types (CSS, JS, images, etc).

The next step is to invalidate them, by using either a query-string, or a version-name.

```
?v=1.2.12
```

or

```
js/my-lib/my-file-1.2.12.js
```

or

js/my-lib/1.2.12/my-file.is

Any of those will work.